# What does a discrete component mixer look like?

Tags: rf, mixer

I'd like to make a poor man's mixer from scratch. Something that can down convert 7MHz to 100KHz. What would the circuit look like using only BJT/FETS or diodes?

EDIT:I found some some using diodes. But those were just passive and when i simulated it i had -20dB attenuation of my IF and I couldn't seem to filter out the -10dB harmonics. This also requires me to somehow add my RF to my LO, which i'm not sure how to do (I have 2 colpitts oscillators).

Comment: What have you found in your research? What was wrong with what you found?

Comment: @Transistor i found some some using diodes. But those were just passive and when i simulated it i had -20dB attenuation of my IF and I couldn't seem to filter out the -10dB harmonics. This also requires me to somehow add my RF to my LO, which i'm not sure how to do (I have 2 colpitts oscillators).

Comment: Right, but add that into your question. Don't hide this info in the comments. Show what you've tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: There was another one using 2 MOS devices but if i use P channel mosfet at high speeds i'd probably need gate drivers which would add to the BOM. And I couldn't seem to simulate this circuit using ideal switches either

Comment: Look up the Gilbert cell.

Comment: In the question, not in the comments ...

Comment: @user110971 My initial intention was to use a Gilbert cell but those ICs don't come in DIP packages. And are ~$3 a pop

Comment: You can build a Gilbert cell out of transistors.

Comment: @user110971 Ya i have parts coming in for such a thing. But i'm not quite sure how to bias the transistors

Comment: Show the diode circuit you simulated and the original. Attenuation needn’t be 20 dB.

Comment: _"What would the circuit look like using **only** BJT/FETS or diodes?"_ - are any other components permitted?

Answer (score 1):

look at the schematic, in the data sheet, for NE602 balanced mixer